# Only rendering first fig.show='animate' code chunk, any that follow are ignored

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

When using the fig.show='animate' option for a code chunk, no other code chunks after are processing. I'm using Windows 8.1 with latest RStudio and R (3.2).

This issue doesn't seem to be a browser related issue. I've tried to output file in multiple browsers and each exhibit the same behavior (see attache image). It seems the HTML code for the second animation (or any after the first) is missing.

Is this a known problem? Can someone verify this is a problem? Or point out what it is that I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TCS"
date: "April 27, 2015"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
x<-runif(100)

```

```{r animation1, echo=FALSE, fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls'}
for (i in 1:20)
  plot(1:i, col=i)
```


```{r}
x<-runif(100)

```

```{r animation2, echo=FALSE, fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls'}
for (i in 20:1)
  plot(1:i, col=i)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Are all packages up-to-date? i.e. `update.packages()`

Comment: yeah, I updated all packages before the result I posted. I noticed a message on here from last fall (that I commented on) where someone had a similar problem - but then they tried it on Ubuntu and it worked. This may be a bug, and is platform specific. Can anyone confirm?